# How do I create an "if-let" block for a gtk call?

Tags: rust, gtk

I am trying to create an application that is using gtk to display a window on the desktop. I am trying to improve the error handling for the code by using "if-let" instead of using "unwrap()" calls. The code right now is:

```
sender.send(AppEvent::QUIT).unwrap();
```

and hoping to turn it into an if-let block

```
if let Some(<need_help_here>) = sender.send(AppEvent::QUIT);
```

I need help with the <need_help_here> part. The `send` function is defined as

```
pub fn send(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), mpsc::SendError<T>>
```

Comment: `Some(...)` is a variant of `Option`. `Result` has the variants `Ok(...)` and `Err(...)`. You likely want to [use the `?` operator to propagate errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator).

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm changing it to ```if let Err(e) = sender.send(AppEvent::QUIT)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function returns a `Result` and not an `Option`, you need to match on `Ok(...)`, not on `Some(...)`:

```
if let Ok(_) = sender.send(AppEvent::QUIT) {
    println!("send successuful");
} else {
    println!("send failed");
}
```

Note that `_` discards the success "value" because it's always `()`, a void "unit" value carrying no information. `Ok(())` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The block should be

```
if Err(e) = sender.send(AppEvent::QUIT) {
  println!("{:?}", e);
}
```